# mit6.828 jos lab1 qemu Triple fault

Tags: operating-system

I prepare the toolchain with the guide [Tools Used in 6.828](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2017/tools.html).
I get a treple fault when runing `lab1`:

[image]

When I comment out the call `memset()` and `monitor()` like the code below, it just runs but the keyboard does not work:

[image]

- toolchain
- gcc version 6.4.0 20170724 (Debian 6.4.0-2)
- GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.29
- GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.29
- lab
- 6.828/ Fall 2017
- qemu
- http://web.mit.edu/ccutler/www/qemu.git -b 6.828-2.3.0

I compare my compiled kernel with other's. I find the elf format of kernel has more sections. like `.got`, `.got.plt`, just the Idx 5 6 7 8 in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaRGv.png)

I think there must be toolchain's faults.Can I do this lab with gcc with new version, how can I do to fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

OK, now I make it.

Compared with the makefile of xv6, I find a option of gcc not present in the GNUmakefile of lab1.

So add `-fno-pic` to `CFLAGS` in GNUMakefile

That will be done.

I will email to staff of 6.828. When they change the file, I will delete this question.